# Missing argument for parameter 'sender' in call

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

I always get this error and I don't know what else to type in.

Do you guys know what's going on?

```
@IBAction func loginAction(sender: AnyObject)
{
    let email = self.emailTextField.text
    let password = self.passwordTextField.text

    if email != "" && password != ""
    {
        FIREBASE_REF.authUser(email, password: password, withCompletionBlock: { (error, authData) -> Void in

            if error == nil
            {
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(authData.uid, forKey: "uid")

                print("Logged in")
                self.logoutButton.hidden = false
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier(String, sender: AnyObject?)
                self.presentViewController(HomeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
            else
            {
              print(error)
            }


        })
    }
    else
    {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Enter Email and Password", preferredStyle: .Alert)

        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)

        alert.addAction(action)

        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

@IBAction func logoutAction(sender: AnyObject)
{
    CURRENT_USER?.unauth()

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(nil, forKey: "uid")
    self.logoutButton.hidden = true
} 
}
```

The error is at the line

self.presentViewVontroller(HomeViewController...

I already created a Segue in the storyboard.

Comment: At least in `performSegueWithIdentifier` you have to pass instances of the types not the types themselves for example the literal identifier of the segue and `self` or `nil` or whatever you need for the sender parameter. And don't use `setValue` with user defaults. it's `setObject`

Comment: Where do you see setValue in the code?

Comment: The literal identifier has to be at the string placeholder, right?

Comment: Yes, there are millions of tutorials here on SO and outside to describe how to do it

Answer (score 0):

if you have created a Segue. firstly select segue and set identifier of Segue.

then perform segue like this

self.performSegueWithIdentifier(identifier, sender: nil)

No need to write this line

self.presentViewController(HomeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)